# Which is the faster way when checking if two strings or RegExp match exactly?

Tags: ruby, string

Which is the faster way (in character level) when checking if two strings or RegExp match exactly? If the string is extremely long or have to check many times?

1. `str == str_or_regexp || str =~ str_or_regexp`
2. `str[str_or_regexp] == str`

Or there is better way?

We don't know `str_or_regexp` is a string or a regular expression until runtime.

Comment: What do you mean "matches a regexp exactly"? It either matches or it doesn't.

Comment: The entire string matches the regexp or another string . Like the one you commented , it could match partially.

Comment: That doesn't clarify. A regexp could match just part of the string if that's what the regexp's pattern dictates.

Comment: Yeah you are right :/ . Just string matches string then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When all else fails, run some tests:

```
str = 'string'
s = 'string'
r = /string/

methods = {
  :equals_or_matches => lambda { |t| str == t || str =~ t },
  :square_brackets => lambda { |t| str[t] == str }
}

methods.each_pair do |name, method|
  puts name

  [s, r].each do |t|
    puts t.class

    5.times do
      start = Time.now
      1000000.times do
        method.call(t)
      end
      puts Time.now - start
    end
  end

  puts
end
```

I got these results:

```
equals_or_matches
String
0.942799
0.942405
0.944376
0.946296
0.93843
Regexp
1.916263
1.915058
1.913306
1.934423
1.932633

square_brackets
String
1.15087
1.157245
1.157863
1.174356
1.188758
Regexp
2.09721
2.103493
2.028035
2.025194
2.037734
```

That indicates that your first method is a little bit faster than your second.

**However,** if the strings are not equal and the `||` doesn't "short circuit", you'll get a `TypeError`. You can't pass a string to `=~`. So you should probably replaced that with `str.match(t)`, which gave me these results:

```
equals_or_matches
String
0.936063
0.94154
0.938561
0.934187
0.935868
Regexp
2.755815
2.75011
2.758374
2.761684
2.76826

square_brackets
String
1.198433
1.160929
1.354407
1.410265
1.274158
Regexp
2.013017
2.275579
2.297108
2.165399
2.125889
```

In that case, your first method fared much worse for regexps, but the second was about the same.

Like I said, just run some tests on real data and see what happens.

Comment: Updates: I changed str=~t to (t.is_a?(Regexp) && str=~t ) so it will "short circuit" str=~t if t is a string. I run your test again, and found a huge performance improvement of 50% faster rate! (I suppose String.match is really not a good one to compare)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `string.match(pattern)` myself and it seems to be the suggested method. Here are the [core docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-match) for it.

Comment: `"foobar".match("foo")` returns `true`, while `"foobar" == "foo"` does not.

Comment: What if str_or_regexp is a string not regexp? It has to match exactly